# Observer in UITableviewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsnotificationcenter

In my custom UITableViewCell I added an observer in NSNotificationCenter:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(stopActivityIndicator) name:@"stopActivityIndicator" object:nil];
```

I post a notification in a UIViewController:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"stopActivityIndicator" object:nil];
```

This function "stopActivityIndicator" is not being called, any idea what causes this?

EDIT:

ExploreViewController.m

```
-(void)showCorrectBannerAfterPlusButtonClicked:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"stopActivityIndicator" object:nil];
}
```

ExploreViewController contains a UITableView with ExploreTableViewCells.

ExploreTableViewCell.m

```
- (IBAction)plusButtonClicked:(id)sender
{
    self.plusButton.hidden = YES;
    [self.plusButtonActivityIndicator startAnimating];


    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(stopActivityIndicator) name:@"stopActivityIndicator" object:nil];

}

-(void)stopActivityIndicator
{
    _plusButton.hidden = NO;
    [self.plusButtonActivityIndicator stopAnimating];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]removeObserver:self name:@"stopActivityIndicator" object:nil];
}
```

Comment: please provide more information about: the signature of `stopActivityIndicator` method; how to subscribe to the notification; and please confirm the name of notification (`"stopActivityIndicator"`) matches everywhere case-sensitively.

Comment: -(void)stopActivityIndicator
{
    _plusButton.hidden = NO;
    [self.plusButtonActivityIndicator stopAnimating];
    
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]removeObserver:self name:@"stopActivityIndicator" object:nil];
}

Comment: ...and how to subscribe it?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, this is the way I'm trying to call the function. Within UIViewcontrollers it works, but adding an UITableViewController as observer seems not to work.

Comment: that is why I'm asking _where_ do you subscribe to the notification?

Comment: In my custom tableviewCell: "ExploreTableViewCell.m"

Comment: well... it is easier to post the relevant code directly, I presume?

Comment: It has to be called when completing a asynchronous (download) function in a ViewController, so I think I can not call it in in  "ExploreTableViewCell.m".

Comment: well... that is not really helpful, honestly, because that does not mean anything without additional context.

Comment: I have added the code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188677/discussion-between-jeegee-and-holex).

Comment: seemingly you are subscribing the notification only after certain user interactions only your cell... have you tried to trigger the user interaction _before_ you expect getting a stop-activity notification?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, question, when do you call "showCorrectBannerAfterPlusButtonClicked"?? As this is the method where you post the notification observed by the tableViewCell.

What I see is the notification observer adding and removal, but I don't see how the UIViewController knows when the cell's "plusButtonClicked" is called, so perhaps the method posting the notification is not being called.

Also, be careful with the cell reusage, have in mind if you should remove the observer at that point.

Comment: It's called in another class, also with posting a notification:  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:@"showCorrectBannerAfterPlusButtonClicked" object:@"S2SObjectAdded"];